# Bitmap won't show in a RemoteView

Tags: android, bitmap, remoteview

When I put a text and a bitmap into an app they both work. The code is:

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("This works");
ImageView testView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
testView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

If I try to put the same text and bitmap into a widget, only the text shows up. The code is:

```
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, "This works");
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView,bitmap);
```

Logcat shows "Failed execv...because non-0 exit status"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the bitmap is too large.

Comment: The bitmap is just a small weather image

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles on this, I found the answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32047849/8183283)

Basically, after calling `setImageViewBitmap`, you need to call `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(COMPONENT_NAME, remoteViews)`, so your code should essentially look something like this:

```
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.your_image_view_id, bitmap)
val COMPONENT_NAME = ComponentName(context, YourEmojiWidget::class.java)
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(COMPONENT_NAME, remoteViews);
```